# Split Large files based on line number, run it and then append the final output into one file

Tags: files, perl, split, r

I am using an R package. The input files required to run in the the package are large(as big as 65 Gb of size)
So I have decided to split the file in chunks based on line number and then merge the Final Output into a single file.
Also I want to do the whole process in PERL.

How should I go about writing a code for the same?

Comment: I need to calculate something in each line of the chunk files.@αғsнιη

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
split -l numberoflines inputfile
```

Huge file will splitted as xaa,xab,xac and so on

finally you can concatenate as `cat xa* >> final_output_file`

If i want to split file for every 65 lines then use below command

example

```
split -l 65 inputfile
```